# How to write an AJAX request to filter posts

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I need to implement the functionality of filtering posts by taxonomies. When clicking on a taxonomy, only those cards that have taxonomy data should remain. Posts are made using the Custom Post Type "speakers". there are two taxonomies with terms "positions" and "countries". How can I write a query to filter on these taxonomies?
My AJAX in JS:

```js
// === AJAX

$('.cat-list_item').on('click', function() {
  $('.cat-list_item').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
      action: 'filter_speakers',
      category: $(this).data('slug'),
    },
    success: function(res) {
      $('.speakers-list').html(res);
    }
  })
});
```

function.php:

```js
// AJAX

function filter_speakers() {

}
add_action('wp_ajax_filter_speakers', 'filter_speakers');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_speakers', 'filter_speakers');
```

Comment: Would you please stop it already, with asking about this again and again and again ... https://stackoverflow.com/q/73386586/1427878 is already about the same topic, and you asked a couple more questions about it that you then deleted again.

Answer (score 0):

In the Ajax filter function:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
  dataType: 'html',
  data: {
    action: 'filter_projects',
    category: $(this).data('slug'),
    type: $(this).data('type'),
  },
  success: function(res) {
    $('.project-tiles').html(res);
  }
});
```

PHP function code:

```
  function filter_projects() {
  $postType = $_POST['type'];
  $catSlug = $_POST['category'];

  $ajaxposts = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => $postType,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'category_name' => $catSlug,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
    'order' => 'desc',
  ]);
  $response = '';

  if($ajaxposts->have_posts()) {
    while($ajaxposts->have_posts()) : $ajaxposts->the_post();
      $response .= get_template_part('templates/_components/project-list-item');
    endwhile;
  } else {
    $response = 'empty';
  }

  echo $response;
  exit;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_filter_projects', 'filter_projects');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_projects', 'filter_projects');
```

Comment: What is $postType = $_POST['type'] and $catSlug = $_POST['category']?

Comment: How can I specify which taxonomies to filter by?